# php and mysql login function issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to fix a problem I've been having with a login form. I've posted the basic html form followed by the php script i'm using. Every time I try to login it doesnt work.

Html - 
    
    
    Username:
    Password:

Php -

```
$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'db', 'pw', 'db');
$login = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" .($_POST[username]) . "') and (password = '" .($_POST[password]) . "')");

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
$_SESSION[username] = $_POST[username];
header('Location: adminpage.php');
}
else {
header('Location: login.html');
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work? What's the error

Comment: You need to be more clear about "it doesnt work".

Comment: I would advise against using `SELECT *`, specially in login forms. Select only what you are going to use.

Comment: Although the information I am entering into the login form is correct, I keep getting returned to the same login form. ie the else function in my php script.

Comment: You should view the php error log on your system. A few of the things you've done should have thrown explanatory errors that would have helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around your $_POST and $_SESSION variables:

`$_POST['username']

$_SESSION['username']`

Also you must use `mysqli_num_rows` since you're using `mysqli`. (not just `mysql_num_rows`)

And make sure you read up on preventing SQL injection.  If you don't clean those $_POST variables before inserting them into an SQL query someone could easily hack into your database.

I've made the changes below:

```
// Make sure to replace the 4 parameters in the next line with your actual database info.
$link = mysqli_connect('THE_URL_TO_YOUR_DATABASE', 'YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_PASSWORD', 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME');
$login = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" .$_POST['username'] . "') and (password = '" .$_POST['password'] . "')");

if (mysqli_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header('Location: adminpage.php');
} else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks mate, finally got it fixed and working! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

change php code with below code:-

```
session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'db', 'pw', 'db');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$login = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND  password = '$password'");

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: adminpage.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: login.html');
}
```

Comment: Ive just put the quotes around my variables, still no change, then changed my query as suggested but again still not change, cant seem to get off the login page. Any other ideas?

Comment: See my answer for one more thing you missed.

Answer (score 0):

**Always make Error Check before performing a Task**

```
session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect('host', 'un', 'pw', 'db');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link))
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Perform a query, check for error
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pswd = $_POST['password'];
$login = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '$user') and (password = '$pswd')");

if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
      header('Location: adminpage.php');    
}else {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```